# Split and rejoin wav files

Tags: bash, wav, sox

I'm trying to edit around 200 wav files with a windows program that won't support command line batch sort of stuff. So it seems like the easiest way to do it would be to combine the wavs into one file (they're all short), and then split them back the way they are after editing.

Sox will give me the length, and I already have the names of course. Is there any way to say, combine all the wavs in a directory into a single wav file, while preserving the names, lengths, and which order they were combined in a txt file, and then use the txt to turn them back into wavs with the original names and lengths?

Edit: I seem to be doing something wrong. I ran this script first:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.wav
do
    dd if=$f of=new_$f bs=1 skip=44
done
```

Then I moved all of the original files out of the folder, deleted the first of the new files, and copied the first of the originals back in. Then I did this:

```
cat *.wav > merged.wav
```

This gives me one file that's as big as it should be, but when I open it with a media player, it just plays the portion that was the first file, and then stops before playing the others.

Answer (score 0):

dont know how creative you want to get. A wav is just a headder with binary data. So long as theyre all the same format, sample size everything, you can use cut or split to strip 44 bytes off the beginming of all of them, keeping one copy of the headder at the beginning, cat them into 1 file, do what you want to them, split it back up using another script with the same list of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can do this.

Assuming all wav files are in c:\temp the command is

```
sox c:\temp\*.wav c:\temp\merged.wav
```

(The example is for windows, for linux use linux path notation)

For preserving the length and names I'd use sox to get the length and
then create a [cue-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_%28computing%29) from that info.

This cue-file can later get used to split the audio.